# Finding cosets of a subgroup of $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the left cosets of subgroup $S_{3}$ generated by $(1,2)$. I know what $\langle (1,2) \rangle = \{ (0,0),(1,2) \}$. I'm just not sure how the answer key got $(1,3)\langle(1,2) \rangle = \{ (1,3), (1,2,3) \}$ and $(2,3) \langle (1,2) \rangle = \{ (2,3), (1,3,2) \}$

Comment: It's the identity, I'm mainly confused as how they got $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$

Comment: I second the comment of JCAA. It seems that $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$, which has 6 objects, by Lagrange's thm. there are subgroups of order 3.

Comment: First of all, $S_3$ is a small group so you can compute the cosets directly. However, some theoretical results might make it a bit easier. As it was already noted, this subgroup has $3$ cosets, each one of them of size $2$. One of them must be $\langle (12)\rangle=\{id, (12)\}$. Since $(13)$ doesn't belong to the subgroup we know that $(13)\langle (12)\rangle$ is a different coset. Compute it, then the remaining two elements must belong to the third coset.

Comment: Maybe an example with the left cosets helps. Consider $H \subset S_3$. In particular take $H=\{(1),(13)\}$ (I still don't know what is (00) in OP post - and in what follows am dropping commas). Then you have that one of the cosets is the subgroup $H$. You can play to get: $(12)H=(132)H$; $(13)H=H$; $(23)H=(123)H$. For example the last case was $(23)H= \{(23),(23)(13)\}=\{(23),(123)\}$. Your case can also be solved by "brute force".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_3=\{(), (12), (13), (23), (123),(132) \}$ is of order $6.$

The subgroup $\langle (12) \rangle= \{(),(12) \}$ is of order $2.$ By Lagrange's theorem, the number of elements of every subgroup divides the order of the group. All cosets have the same number of elements, and partition the group. Hence, there are $3$ cosets of $2$ elements each.

We can look for elements of $S_3$ outside of the subgroup $\langle (12) \rangle$ and multiply them on the left by all the elements of $\langle (12) \rangle.$ Since subgroups are closed under multiplication, there is no point in multiplying by elements of the subgroup.

In the OP the first line of the solution involves multiplying on the left the subgroup by $(13)$ with the permutations applied from right to left:

$$(13)(12)=(123)$$

because $1$ goes to $2$ in the transposition on the right, i.e. $(12),$ and it is not moved anywhere else by the transposition on the left, i.e. $(13).$ The next element to consider is $2,$ which goes to $1$ by $(12)$ and then goes to $3$ by $(13).$ Finally $3$ is not moved on the right transposition, but goes to $1$ on the left transposition.

Evidently, multiplying $(13)$ times the identity element will not change it. Therefore the first coset found is

$$(13)\langle (12) \rangle=\{(13), (123) \}$$

And we have the other remaining elements constituting the last coset: $\{(23),(132)\}.$

Comment: Thank you, can I just ask why did they use (1,3) and (2,3) to multiply with (1,2)?

Comment: You can use any element. However, if the element you choose is already in the subgroup to begin with, the multiplication will land where it started: with some element of the subgroup. Hence, $(12)$ will not "displace" the original subgroup into a different coset. So they chose one of the other two transposition in the group, $(13)$ and $(23),$ to isolate one coset, leaving the last one coset determined.